# Rewrite a bash for loop as a while loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop

As an in-class exercise my professor has asked the class to rewrite this `for` loop (which works) as either a `while` loop or an `until` loop.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

#go to home directory
cd ~

for entry in `ls`
do  
    if [ -d "$entry"] ; then
        echo "Dir: $entry"
    else
        echo "File: $entry"
    fi  
done
```

Comment: This use of `ls` is an anti-pattern. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor for why.

Comment: Since your professor wants you to learn: Research how while loops work: What is the main characteristic of a while loop compare to a for loop. List how they behave different, and then you can write it.

Comment: For operating on the contents of a directory a `for` loop is the natural (and correct) model. Do you have more instruction on how the `while`/`until` logic is supposed to work here? Is it just "loop over all files"?

Comment: Assuming the use of `ls` is just an example program (should use globbing, and back-ticks are deprecated anyway) research *process substitution*.

Comment: What we are supposed to do is make the script perform the same function as it does now, just using a while or until loop instead

Answer (score 0):

This is 1:1 mapping to your example (*SAME limitations: e.g. no \n characters in filenames*):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r entry
do
    if [ -d "$entry" ]; then
        echo "Dir : $entry"
    else
        echo "File: $entry"
    fi
done < <(ls)
```

Comment: Your code works and I appreciate the help, but I need to edit my code above to do what yours does.  I cant just turn in all new code.